# sql count() get wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this structure:

```
|  event id  | item 1 id | item 2 id |   set   |
|     1      |     1     |     2     |    1    |
|     1      |     1     |     3     |    1    |
|     1      |     2     |     1     |    1    |
|     1      |     2     |     3     |    1    |
|     1      |     3     |     1     |    1    |
|     1      |     3     |     2     |    1    |
|     1      |     2     |     4     |    2    |
|     1      |     4     |     2     |    2    |
|     2      |     1     |     4     |    3    |
|     2      |     1     |     5     |    3    |
|     2      |     4     |     1     |    3    |
|     2      |     4     |     5     |    3    |
|     2      |     5     |     1     |    3    |
|     2      |     5     |     4     |    3    |
```

now I wish to count the occurrence of item1 as well as item1 combined with item2 separately

I tried following:

```
with count_item1 AS (
    select event_id, item_1_id, count(distinct set) AS c1 from table
    group by event_id, item_1_id
), count_item1_and_item2 AS (
    select event_id, item_1_id, item_2_id, count(distinct set) AS c2 from table
    group by event_id, item_1_id, item_2_id
)
select t1.event_id, t1.item_1_id, t1.item_2_id, t1.c2, t2.c1
from count_item1_and_item2 AS t1
inner join count_item1 AS t2
on t1.event_id=t2.event_id and t1.item_1_id=t2.item_1_id
```

for example as table above 
so the result for this should be:

```
|  event id  | item 1 id | item 2 id |   c1   |   c2   |
|      1     |     1     |     2     |    1   |    1   |
|      1     |     1     |     3     |    1   |    1   |
|      1     |     2     |     1     |    2   |    1   |
|      1     |     2     |     3     |    2   |    1   |
|      1     |     3     |     1     |    1   |    1   |
|      1     |     3     |     2     |    1   |    1   |
|      1     |     2     |     4     |    2   |    1   |
|      1     |     4     |     2     |    1   |    1   |
|      2     |     1     |     4     |    1   |    1   |
|      2     |     1     |     5     |    1   |    1   |
|      2     |     4     |     1     |    1   |    1   |
|      2     |     4     |     5     |    1   |    1   |
|      2     |     5     |     1     |    1   |    1   |
|      2     |     5     |     4     |    1   |    1   |
```

the meaning of each row is: in event_id, item 1 appeared c1 in distinct set and (item1, item2) appeared c2 in distinct set. 
also count of (item1, item2) is equal to (item2, item1)

then I find a strange thing:
the occurrence of item1 itself should not less than the occurrence of item1 combined with item2, but I find that sometimes item1 combined with item2 has more count than count of item1, is there anything I did wrong here? I think my idea is right but I didn't get the result. I have being stacked in here for a weekend.

Comment: Please post the complete expected results ...

Comment: It would be more helpful to give us some details about your problem instead of the errors in the fetched results

Comment: What your query is asking for, is the count of distinct occurrences of the pair (item1,item2). But what you want is the sum of both counts. What you can do is to prepare two separate queries in the style of your first and then a third, selecting both counts and adding them with a simple plus.

Comment: Your expected result is exactly what you get by your code. Just flip the 2 columns, instead of `t1.c2, t2.c1` write `t2.c1, t1.c2`